# How to set list item height according to display resolution

Tags: android, xml, list

I have a **listview**, and one list item consist of two **textview's** and an **imageview**(actual image is downloaded from server with help of ION library). I want to fit exactly 3 list items on the screen, but as screen resolutions vary I cant do it simply with setting item height.

What i've tried is:

```
vi_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)(MainActivity.screenHeight*0.33));
userImage.setLayoutParams(vi_params);
```

But this gives event different result - no image is shown at all.

This is how my list_item.xml looks like.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_x="0dp"

    android:layout_y="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ID"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, any ideas how to make list item height depending on screen height, so only three would fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just as I thought, multiplying integer by 0.33 was returning 0, so i used DIVISION:
"userImage.getLayoutParams().height = MainActivity.height / 3;

Anyways, i still don't get wanted result, because actionBar still takes place.

So i just got it with:

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        {
            actionbarheight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
```

And still it wasnt perfect, so i got myself height of titlebar:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() { 
          int result = 0;
          int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
          if (resourceId > 0) {
              result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
          } 
          return result;
    }
```